# How can I solve v-autocomplete menu is not hiding behind mobile keyboard? (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, autocomplete, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm having problems in my vuetify project. I tried on the vuetify website and it turns out this problem also occurs. Look at this :

[image]

Reference : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#autocompletes

My component like this :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-autocomplete
        label="Components"
        :items="components"
      ></v-autocomplete>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Demo and full code : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/GRRLXXP?&editable=true&editors=101

You can try it on your mobile version. This makes me unable to do searching

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [docs&examples page](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/autocompletes) for this component. It goes up because there is no enough space on the screen. It works the same in examples on their docs page. It seems to be its native normal behaviour. The css `top` property for  `.v-menu__content` is recalculated (`68px` -> `12px`) based on the available space. You could override styles for all/mobile dimensions like

```
.v-menu__content.theme--light.menuable__content__active.v-autocomplete__content {
    top: 68px!important;
}
```

Although I personally wouldn't do that.

Comment: why don't you personally want to do that? users cannot search autocomplete if you do not do that

Comment: because it is native behaviour that seems ok to me. They can - when you see picture like in your post where dropdown list overlaps input - the focus is actually on the input and users can type in symbols. Although the final choice is up to you.

Comment: What you mean `users can type in symbols`?

Comment: if that dropdown list is open I still can press buttons and symbols will be in the input which will result in changes in the dropdown list.

Comment: Yeah. but looks strange

Comment: it depends. You migt submit an issue https://issues.vuetifyjs.com/

Comment: Okay. For example I follow your way. `top: 68px!important;`, It does not seem dynamic because each device has a different size